# Salesforce SOQl query

Tags: soql

Is there any possibility of querying the fields using datatype. I need to query the email field of multiple objects. Email field names are different. So I am trying to get the data using the email datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SOSL for this, [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000ADF3IAO) is an example of using SOSL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SOSL to query multiple objects and there is a search group in SOSL to limit it to search only email fileds

Syntax :FIND 'SearchQuery' [IN SearchGroup] [RETURNING ObjectsAndFields]

Eg : FIND 'SearchQuery' IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING Obj1(filed1,fileds2) , Obj2(filed1,fileds2)

SearchGoup accept following groups

```
ALL FIELDS
NAME FIELDS
EMAIL FIELDS
PHONE FIELDS
SIDEBAR FIELDS
```